# Can Dirac Delta Function Test Functions Be Less Restrictive Than Schwartz Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, dirac-delta

I understand that, in $L^2$ Hilbert space, functions do not exist pointwise, so if function $\phi(x) \in L^2$, we cannot speak of a specific value $\phi (0)$, at $x=0$, and so we cannot say $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \delta (x) dx = \phi (0)$.

But if we look at the space of functions, $\psi(x)$ (with $x \in R$), that both exist pointwise (so that $\psi(x)$ has a specifically defined value for any $-\infty \leq x \leq \infty$) and are square integrable from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, then does it make sense to let $\delta (x)$ act on those such that we can say: $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \psi(x) \delta (x) dx = \psi (0)$? I know that this simple definition of $\psi(x)$ does not guarantee the existence of the derivative of the delta function in this space but, that not withstanding, I think that $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \psi(x) \delta (x) dx = \psi (0)$ would still be true for those $\psi(x)$, especially if we define $$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \psi(x) \delta (x) dx \equiv \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \psi(x) \delta_n (x) dx$$ with something like $\delta_n (x) \equiv \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} \exp (-nx^2)$

What I am getting at is that it seems to me that the space of test functions for $\delta (x)$ need not be something as restrictive as Schwartz (S) or Kantorovich (K) space.

Comment: The Schwartz space is the largest space such that : the distributions with compact support and their Fourier transform are **continuous** when acting on it. If you restrict to distributions of order $0$ as the $\delta$ and forget about the Fourier tansform, then you can consider a larger space, for example the space of piecewise continuous functions

Comment: @ user1952009. Thanks. But  $FT(\delta(x-t) ) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x-t)  exp(-ipx) dx=exp(-ipt)$.   When $exp(-ipt)$ is a functional acting on some function space, it can still do so in a continuous manner without that function space having to be as restrictive as Schwartz space, I think.

Comment: For instance, if the test function space is that of absolutely integrable functions then, I believe, FTs are continuous in that space. Therefore, by the definition of FT of a distribution, FTs of distributions that act on the space of absolutely integrable functions are also continuous. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. If you want to keep the FT, then look at $L^1 \cap FT[L^1]$ which is a space of continuous and $L^1$ functions whose FT is continuous and $L^1$. Hence both $\langle \delta,\varphi \rangle$ and  $\langle 1,\varphi \rangle$ are well-defined for $\varphi$ in that space.

Answer (score 2):

Your example fails; consider $\psi$ given by

$$ \psi(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = 0 \\ 0 & x \neq 0 \end{cases} $$

$\psi$ is square integrable,

$$ \psi(0) \neq 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(x) \delta_n(x) \, \mathrm{d} x $$

so in the dual space to square-integrable functions, $\delta \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} \delta_n$.

---

The most reasonable general space to find delta distributions is, in my opinion, in the dual space to the space of  *continuous* functions, if you simply want them to *exist*.

---

But you should pay attention to the fact that, usually, the point isn't simply to define delta distributions — instead one wants to define a space that:

- Contains the objects of interest
- Admits all of the sorts of calculations we want in our application
- Has good analytical properties

The second point is very important. For example, in physics, Fourier transforms are very important, which makes the space of tempered distributions (on Schwartz functions) a popular one to work within.